# Python | Django | Empty fields from Forms

Tags: python, django, model, field

I have some problem
This is my code:

views.py:

```
def cv_detail(request, pk):
    cv = get_object_or_404(Cv, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'cv_detail.html', {'cv': cv})
```

cv_detail.html:

```
{% block profile %}
<a class="btn-lg btn-default" href="{% url "edit_cv" pk=cv.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> Edit</span></a>
<p></p><br>
<div class="jumbotron">

    {% if not cv.specialization.is_empty %}
        <p>Specialization: {{cv.specialization}}</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py:

```
class CvForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Cv
        fields = ('name', 'specialization',)
```

models.py:

```
class Cv(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null = True)
    specialization = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    def zapisz(self):
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.surname
```

And the question is: how can i check is any field of cv model is empty?
I have nothing in "Specialization" - is not complemented by me, so shouldn't be displayed, but it is, like: "Specialization: ".

Any ideas how to check? Becouse that what i have is not working :/

Thanks!

Comment: Is `blank=True` intended? It means it can be blank so the validation passes. Otherwise you can just do `if not cv.specialization` in your view. Both empty string and `None` will evaluate to `False`.

Comment: What do you mean? I Try with "None" but it's not working. How u see your proposition in my view? I Have more fields, not only "specialization".

Comment: Oh, sorry it is obviously `if cv.specialization`. Also i don't quite understand "How u see your proposition in my view?".

Comment: @Damian I don't think you are stating your questions incorrectly. Your questions is: "how can I check is any field of CV model is empty?". The answer is, do this: "if cv.specialization" or "if cv.name" or "if cv.author" to check if a CV field is empty (as Ivan mentioned). Is that the question you wanted to ask?

Comment: Yes, that's it, It's working great. But i have another question, how can i put this in for-loop? This tempalte have PrimaryKey, so i can't use {% for cv in cvs %} -  as i wrote, i used pk here, and also there is no something like "cvs" in views.py so can't. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for an empty `specialization` field in your template with:

```
{% if cv.specialization and cv.specialization.strip %}
    <p>Specialization: {{cv.specialization}}</p>
{% endif %}
```

The `.strip` check will ensure that you do not attempt to display a string that only contains whitespaces.

Comment: .strip ? What does it mean?